# Switching from Python 3.5 to 2.7 at the end of a script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I use Anaconda and I have Python 3.5 installed. I use this (mainly pandas) to process files everyday.

I want to add writing a .tde file for Tableau at the end of one of my scripts. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_installing.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____3

This seems to require Python 2.7 though. I would prefer not to mix everything up and I have absolutely no experience in virtual environments and so forth.

My goal is to basically complete my file processing (using python 3.5 as usual) and then as a final step (a final cell in a Jupyter notebook, to be specific) do something like...

```
import python2
import tableausdk

#script to create the .tde file
```

Can someone outline some specific steps I should take to complete this without causing a big headache or future problems?

Comment: No, you can't do that within Python.

Comment: If you want to use Python 3 for the main part and Python 2 for the final step, you could export the data in some version-independent way, and then call the Python 2 script which imports it again.

Comment: Contact the writer of that library and ask him to port it to python3. If enough users ask him to do that he'll eventually realize he should have ported that library long ago.  Alternatively you could try use use directly the C library via `ctypes`. If you want to just use a few commands `ctypes` may be enough.

Comment: So what I can do is write a .csv.bz2 file, for example, at the end of my Python 3 script. Then, in a separate script, I can read that file and just do the .tde steps?

I was looking at the Anaconda documentation and saw: 

conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda

Is this what I should do to make a 2.7 version that I can open? How do I  use that version within my python script?

Comment: @LanceDacey see my edit

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is to create a file with the result of the python 3 part of the work and then launch the python 2 script with the file as argument using `os.system` or the `subprocess` module but to do that you will need to be able to split your task into 2 parts

But it will be impossible to do that with only running a python3 interpreter

To launch your second script you don't need virtualenvs just use the python2 interpreter explicitly

example on debian:

```
os.system("/bin/python2 python2_script.py mydata.file")
```

or windows

```
os.system("c:\python27\python.exe python2_script.py mydata.file")
```

EDIT: To use this with anaconda

you can create an py27 environment with

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

This will create a python interpreter a this location:

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\py27\python.exe
```

and your python3 script should invoke it this way for example

```
os.system("C:\Anaconda\envs\py27\python.exe python2_script.py mydata.csv.bz2")
```